# For WMV files avformat_find_stream_info() shows "Extra data: 8 bits left, value: 0" message

Tags: ffmpeg, libavformat

When I call avformat_find_stream_info() for wmv files, the following message is always seen:
*[wmv3 00FAEAE0] Extra data: 8 bits left, value: 0*

After that the program works as expected but anyway I would like to know what does that message mean? Thank you!

File info (by ffmpeg -i):

```
Duration: 00:00:06.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1514 kb/s
Stream #0:0(rus): Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
Stream #0:1(rus): Video: wmv3 (Main) (WMV3 / 0x33564D57), yuv420p, 720x576, 1368 kb/s, SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
```

Code:

```
AVFormatContext*    pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, "file.wmv", NULL, NULL) < 0)
    return 0;
if (avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL) < 0) // HERE WE HAVE GOT THAT MESSAGE
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The message is printed by libavcodec/vc1dec.c, in function vc1_decode_init(). That function initializes a VC1/WMV3 decoder.  At that point, it's parsed the WMV3 header, and thinks that the file has a sequence header stored in the extradata; also, that the advanced sequence header may be before the first frame; and finally, that the extradata's final byte is a version number.

This interpretation may be inexact, because it's based on comments as bereft of punctuation and capitalization as e. e. cummings poetry.

Judging purely from the source code, though, "what that message means" is simply that a header was one byte longer than expected, and that that byte's value was zero.  (As a wise man once said, debug the code, not the comments.)